# Amazon Route 53 DNS Reverse Lookup Zone - ATT IP Block Setup

Tags: amazon-web-services, routes, dns, reverse

I cannot get reverse DNS lookup configured correctly in Amazon Route 53 for a block of ATT IP's that have been delegated to Amazon Name Servers.

So, I have a block of IP's assigned to me by ATT.  The block is `12.237.40.64/27`.  ATT has delegate the block to Amazon Name Servers.  I start by doing a `dig -x` on one of the IP's in the block - `.65`, and get the following:

```
;; ANSWER SECTION:

65.40.237.12.in-addr.arpa. 86400 IN     CNAME   65.64/27.40.237.12.in-addr.arpa.
```

So I start to create a zone in Amazon Route 53 with the name `65.64/27.40.237.12.in-addr.arpa`  < this value is being entered into the 'Domain Name' field with in Amazon Route 53 in the UI.  Once created and saved, Route 53 actually names the zone:

```
65.64\05727.40.237.12.in-addr.arpa
```

Not sure why this is happening.  It seems that the CNAME entry from ATT about will never find the zone `65.64/27.40.237.12.in-addr.arpa`  ??  So I continue and assume that some sort of translation will occur from the CNAME entry to the zone name I view on screen within route 53.  Once the zone is created. I proceed to try to add a PTR record in Route 53.  Route 53 will only allow me to prepend the zone name with an ip so the result is:

```
65.65.64\05727.40.237.12.in-addr.arpa PTR server.mydomain.com
```

The result I want would be:

```
65.40.237.12.in-addr.arpa. PTR     server.mydomain.com.
```

So I add a new zone file and name the zone `40.237.12.in-addr.arpa`.  I then add the PTR record for `.65` with in the block.  I then `dig -x 12.237.40.65 @amz.name.server`, and I get the desired result:

```
;; ANSWER SECTION:

65.40.237.12.in-addr.arpa. 300  IN      PTR     server.mydomain.com.
```

So the problem seems to be that I cannot name the Route 53 zone to agree with the CNAME delegation from ATT ??

I found an article ([PDF](http://planner.bus.att.com/tab010a.pdf)) on ATT delegated IP blocks.

Can anyone give me some direction on setting up reverse DNS on Amazon route 53 correctly?  Or do I need to contact ATT to change the CNAME entry to a different format that I can add and save in route 53?

Answer (score 0):

`65.64/27.40.237.12.in-addr.arpa.` and `65.65.64\05727.40.237.12.in-addr.arpa PTR server.mydomain.com` are just slightly differently formatted names for the same thing. `\057` is the octal code for `/`. It looks like you've configured the domain correctly ...

```
colmmacc@colmmac] dig NS 64/27.40.237.12.in-addr.arpa. @ns-1175.awsdns-18.org
<snip>
;; QUESTION SECTION:
;64/27.40.237.12.in-addr.arpa.  IN  NS

;; ANSWER SECTION:
64/27.40.237.12.in-addr.arpa. 3600 IN   NS  ns-1175.awsdns-18.org.
64/27.40.237.12.in-addr.arpa. 3600 IN   NS  ns-1967.awsdns-53.co.uk.
64/27.40.237.12.in-addr.arpa. 3600 IN   NS  ns-281.awsdns-35.com.
64/27.40.237.12.in-addr.arpa. 3600 IN   NS  ns-593.awsdns-10.net.
```

and the reverse DNS entry seems to be working too:

```
colmmacc@colmmacc] dig -x 12.237.40.65 

;; QUESTION SECTION:
;65.40.237.12.in-addr.arpa. IN  PTR

;; ANSWER SECTION:
65.40.237.12.in-addr.arpa. 86400 IN CNAME   65.64/27.40.237.12.in-addr.arpa.
65.64/27.40.237.12.in-addr.arpa. 300 IN PTR smtpwin.omnilink.com.
```

Route 53 merely escapes all non-alpha-numerical characters for display, but the `/` and `\057`
 are equivalent.